# Find and replace subscripts and superscripts in MS Excel

Tags: html, excel

I would like to find all numbers and formulas which contain subscripts and superscripts in excel cells and replace it with html tags for subscripts and superscripts.

Eg. cell containing **a<sup>2</sup> + (b<sup>3</sup> - c)** would be replaced as:

```html
a<sup>2</sup> + (b<sup>3</sup> - c)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look into developing a vba solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
Dim ColNo, RowNo As Long
Dim NewStr As String

Set ws1 = Worksheets("q")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("q-a")
ws1.Activate

With ws1
    RowNo = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    ColNo = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    For i = 1 To ColNo
        For j = 1 To RowNo
            l = 1
            NewStr = .Cells(j, i).Value2
            For k = 1 To Len(.Cells(j, i).Value2) - 1
                If .Cells(j, i).Characters(k + 1, 1).Font.Superscript = True Then
                    NewStr = Mid(NewStr, 1, k - 1 + l) & "<sup>" & Mid(.Cells(j, i) _ 
                           .Value2, k + 1, 1) & "</sup>" & Mid(.Cells(j, i).Value2, _
                                  k + 2, Len(.Cells(j, i).Value2) - (k + 1))
                    l = l + 11
                ElseIf .Cells(j, i).Characters(k + 1, 1).Font.Subscript = True Then
                    NewStr = Mid(NewStr, 1, k - 1 + l) & "<sub>" & Mid(.Cells(j, i)._ 
                            Value2, k + 1, 1) & "</sub>" & Mid(.Cells(j, i).Value2, _
                                  k + 2, Len(.Cells(j, i).Value2) - (k + 1))
                    l = l + 11
                End If
            Next
            l = 1
            For k = 1 To Len(NewStr) - 1
                If InStr(k, NewStr, "</sup><sup>", vbBinaryCompare) = k Then
                    NewStr = Mid(NewStr, 1, k - 1) & Mid(NewStr, k + 11, Len(NewStr) - (k + 10))
                ElseIf InStr(1, NewStr, "</sub><sub>", vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
                    NewStr = Mid(NewStr, 1, k - 1) & Mid(NewStr, k + 11, Len(NewStr) - (k + 10))
                End If
            Next
            ws2.Cells(j, i).Value2 = NewStr
            NewStr = ""
        Next
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

According with the new information, I just make it simpler.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As far as I try, that one works always but fail on the first character. So if the firs character is Subscript or Superscript, it will fail.

The code it is for the superscript case. For the subscript case, just change `.Font.Subscript` by `.Font.Superscript` and whatever code on html (`<sup>` on the superscript).

```
Sub test()
Dim ColNo, RowNo As Long
Dim Pos(500) As Integer
Dim Str(500) As String
Dim sType(500) as String
Dim NewStr As String

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Hoja1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Hoja2")
ws1.Activate

With ws1
    RowNo = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    ColNo = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    l = 2
    For i = 1 To ColNo
        For j = 1 To RowNo
            Pos(1) = 1
            For k = 1 To Len(.Cells(j, i).Value2) - 1
                If .Cells(j, i).Characters(k + 1, 1).Font.Superscript = True Then
                    Pos(l) = k + 1
                    sType(l) = "Sup"
                    l = l + 1
                ElseIf .Cells(j, i).Characters(k + 1, 1).Font.Subscript = True Then
                    Pos(l) = k + 1
                    sType(l) = "Sub"
                    l = l + 1
                End If
            Next
            For k = 1 To l - 1
                If Pos(k + 1) > Pos(k) Then
                    If sType(l + 1) = "Sup" Then
                        Str(2 * k) = Mid(.Cells(j, i).Value2, Pos(k), Pos(k + 1) - Pos(k))
                        Str(2 * k - 1) = Mid(.Cells(j, i).Value2, Pos(k + 1), 1)
                        Str(2 * k - 1) = "<sup>" & Str(2 * k - 1) & "</sup>"
                        NewStr = NewStr & Str(2 * k) & Str(2 * k - 1)
                    ElseIf sType(l + 1) = "Sub" Then
                        Str(2 * k) = Mid(.Cells(j, i).Value2, Pos(k), Pos(k + 1) - Pos(k))
                        Str(2 * k - 1) = Mid(.Cells(j, i).Value2, Pos(k + 1), 1)
                        Str(2 * k - 1) = "<sub>" & Str(2 * k - 1) & "</sub>"
                        NewStr = NewStr & Str(2 * k) & Str(2 * k - 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If NewStr <> "" Then
                NewStr = NewStr + Mid(.Cells(j, i).Value2, _
                                  Pos(l - 1), Len(.Cells(j, i).Value2) - Pos(l - 1))
            Else
                NewStr = .Cells(j, i).Value2
            End If
            ws2.Cells(j, i).Value2 = NewStr
            NewStr = ""
            For k = 1 To l - 1
                Pos(k) = 0
                sType(k) = ""
                Str(2 * k) = ""
                Str(2 * k - 1) = ""
            Next
            l = 2
        Next
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works but in some cases it converts sub/superscript into <sub> / <sup> elements but content between these tags does not delete and stays in the result. Eg. p^1 * V^1 converts into p<sup>1</sup>1*V<sup>2</sup>2

Comment: Is it randomly? Could you send one section as sample?

Comment: I have solved that problem, but I have one more question, How can I combine those scripts? I want to find all subscripts and all subscripts during one run time, if I run both algorithms one by one it does not work as expected

Comment: The issue, I did not consider, is that if you have sub and superscripts in the same word, as soon as you use "ws2.Cells(j, i).Value2 = NewStr", the format is lost, so you can not apply the same algorythm again. Have you got Sub and Superscripts on the same words?

Comment: No I do not have sub/superscripts in the same word, so that should not be a problem. But I do not know how to combine algorithms. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I am replying from my mobile... so maybe there will be something wrong, because I can not check. But the idea I introduce is just create a second matrix so that one will take the kind of script (Sup or Sub) you have, so later you have a double conditional to add <sub> or <sup>, depends of the case. Please check it.

Comment: I have checked but i do not know what is wrong :( can you please have a look when you will be on the computer? Thanks a lot

Comment: With my samples it is working. Could you send me one sample?

Comment: Here is a sample (https://gofile.io/?c=fCSJOv) with which it does not work

Comment: There are, in the sheet called "q", the sheet "q-a" contains results of the script. I have change  lines Set ws1 = Worksheets("q/q-a") in the script